# failed to /init - Newbie here does not know how to proceed

Tags: boot, init

I'm using Ubuntu as a roundabout way to get my xbox one hd upgraded. I made all preparations last night, including the booting of Ubuntu in order to run several scripts that would do the job for me. All went fine, but it was late and decided to wait until this morning.

I'm using the same laptop, whose configuration I haven't changed, except for the UEFI/secure boot settings, which last night prevented me from booting Ubuntu.

This morning, all excited, I tried booting from a USB pendrive, using the same exact BIOS settings, but Ubuntu would halt with the following:

```
failed to execute /init (error -2)
```

I have read many postings and their supposed 'solutions', but all of them assume some knowledge of Ubuntu. I don't have any, so anything explained does not make sense to me. In fact, I don't even get to a command line from which I could attempt to follow instructions.

I'm running a Toshiba Satellite S855 i7 4th gen, 16GB RAM, 512GB SSD HD, AMD video, etc. I don't think the hardware has any bearing on this failure. It booted successfully, once, but never again!

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? What device are you booting it from (CD, USB drive, internal SSD)? You can [edit] to add details.

Comment: These two bits seem contradictory: *"... whose configuration I haven't changed, except for the UEFI/secure boot settings"*, and *" ... using the same exact BIOS settings"*

Comment: Is there anything else on the screen when that error appears? If yes, could you add a screenshot?

Comment: I was finally able, by chance, to boot successfully. I simply disabled the 'Secure boot' option and left the related boot options alone. I forget what they are called. I seem to remember AHCP/Compatibility/CMOS. Anyway, thank you for those who tried to help.